# Jquery load event on select elements loaded through Ajax

Tags: jquery, load

I am loading MVC partial views using ajax. Jquery documentation about `load` says

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()

That's why it wont work with elements loaded through ajax.
I know I can put this logic in each partial views  However is there a way or better solution to have it only at one place (in main view onto which partial views are loaded)

```
$('select').load(function () {
                $(this).somewidget();
            });
```

Comment: Could you show us the `on()` function that you have already?

Comment: I don't have the implementation of on() function. As per documentation .load() is short cut for .on('load', handler) (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)